# Trouble getting revision number out of svn for spec file

Tags: svn, shell, rpm, specifications

I'm working on a spec file where I want to use the revision number of the SVN repo as part of the version number.

If I use just:

```
%(svnversion -c %{sourcedir})
```

Then I get PackageName-1-209:299 where 299 is the revision number. So I am trying to crop out the "1-209" section as it's consistently there and doesn't change.

The line I'm having issues with is:

```
%(svnversion -c %{sourcedir} | sed 's/^1\-209://')
```

What I seem to get out from this is PackageName209:299 still.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You probably should try another regular expression:

```
%(svnversion -cn %{sourcedir} | sed -r 's/.+://')
```

However, note that svnversion may also add some letters in the end (M if there are local modifications, S - if it is the switched working copy). Do you need to check them - is up to you.

PS

There is a faster way to get the current revision (since svnrevision requests svn server to collect data) described [here](http://www.zorched.net/2006/07/20/getting-the-revision-number-of-your-subversion-working-copy/):

```
grep revision .svn/entries |  awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

However, this will not work for svn since version 1.7.